# if condition is not working properly in the code which is one of the task in codeacademy

Tags: python

https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/python-beginner-P5YtY/1/6?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):

  if city== "Tampa" or "tampa":
      return 220 
  elif city== "Charlotte" or "charlotte":
      return 183
  elif city== "Pittsburgh" or "pittsburgh":
      return 222
  elif city== "Los Angeles" or "los angeles":
      return 474
```

In this code, which when submitted to codeacedemy it returns 220 only that is the first return value, except it nothing is checked I guess?

Comment: the code executes as `city == (true or true)` -> `city == true`. you can't do  `somevalue == val Or val or val or`, the `or` are parsed/executed first and reduced to a single boolean true/false. you need `city == "Tampa" or city == "tampa"` e.g. read this: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html   section 5.15 "operator precedence"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
if city == "Tampa" or city == "tampa":
```

Or

```
if city in ("Tampa", "tampa"):
```

Another option for strings is use `lower` method (If you want a case-insensitive comparisson)

```
if city.lower() == "tampa":
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure to check the value of city against both values:

i.e.

```
if city == "Tampa" or city == "tampa":
    # do stuff
```

Otherwise, Python will interpret this as if `(city == "Tampa") or ("tampa")`, the latter of which will always evaluate to `True`

Alternatively, if you want to check multiple conditions in a list, you can put the values in an array:

```
tampa = ["Tampa", "tampa"]
if city in tampa:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check the value of city against two different values at the same time like that.

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city == "Tampa" or city == "tampa":
      return 220 
  elif city == "Charlotte" or city == "charlotte":
      return 183
  elif city == "Pittsburgh" or city == "pittsburgh":
      return 222
  elif city == "Los Angeles" or city == "los angeles":
      return 474
```

OR

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city in ["Tampa","tampa"]:
      return 220 
  elif city in ["Charlotte","charlotte"]:
      return 183
  elif city in ["Pittsburgh","pittsburgh"]:
      return 222
  elif city in ["Los Angeles","los angeles"]:
      return 474
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if city in ["Tampa", "tampa"]:
    #code
```

or

```
if city.lower() == "tampa":
    #code
```